# popToRootViewController not working when sending from add screen

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a simple app I am building. A list of items in 1 view controller with a table view and embedded navigation controller. When you select a row it brings you to the details screen (no problem).

**Push from List View to List Item**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ListItemDetailsVC", sender: nil)
}
```

**Pop back from list item to List View**

```
@IBAction func backToInboxTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This works fine!

My issue is that I have another view controller (add item) that presents modally when add button is clicked. The idea is that when it saves it brings you to the list detail vc.

```
@IBAction func saveItem(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailsFromAdd", sender: nil)
}
```

Opening up the details view controller from the add new controller works fine but once I open the details view I want to be able to go back to the rootViewController. The button does not work anymore

[image]

Comment: when your `backToInboxTapped` functione get called ? and from which VC ?

Comment: Can you show your pushing code. I suspect the problem is in there.

Comment: @Lion I have a button on ListItemDetails view controller

Comment: maybe this answer will help you by using an unwind segue http://stackoverflow.com/a/40248196/5327882

Comment: Since addItem controller is push modally, u need to call dismissViewController method rather than popToRootViewController

Comment: try to call dismissViewController..

Comment: what is `saveItem` ? is it for `add list item` to `list item details` ? and show your code that how you present `add list item` from `list view controller`! Because your segue seems to be for `show - i.e. push` not for `modally present`!

Comment: its a button on AddListItemVC that saves a new list item

Answer (score 3):

In your case you should not need to use segue. You have to clear some concepts.

You can't `popToRootViewController` or `VC` if you have pushed or show view controller from `modally presented vc`!!

Now if you want to achieve this then you have to make some changes that I am trying to mention below :

take one global variable or property (objective c concept) in your `add item VC`. now when you come to `add item VC` from `lust VC` set this global variable or property to `self` something like,

```
   AddListItemVC *advc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addListItem"];  // addListItem is storyboard id for viewcontroller




[self presentViewController:advc animated:NO completion:^{


    advc.vc = self;  // here vc is the propery of type `UIVIewController` declare in AddListItemVC

}];
```

Now your code for going to `details VC` from `add list VC` should be like,

```
    DetailListViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewScreen"];   // detailViewScreen is storyboard id which you can set from identity inspector



[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{


    [self.vc.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];  // here self.vc is global variable or property that contains reference of first VC (i.e. list view controller)


}];
```

no need to use `performsegue` in this case. You can use `performsegue` to go in `detailvc` directly from firstvc i mean from `list vc`.

Hope you got understand concept and i have written objective c snippet because of lake of time!! hope you can easily convert to swift!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, As you say that addVC is modally presenting so make sure addVC have some navigation otherwise you'll not able to push listItemVC from addVC.

Now second thing, when you're modally presenting addVC then push listItemVC pushed from addVC, now addVC navigation controller have two view controllers. When you call `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` this will bring you to addVC because is being presented thats's why you will not able to see listVC.
To solve this you've to add some dismiss presented view controller whenever you'll arrive at addVC.